# Take database entry with URL and title and show on page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a profile form that takes a URL as an entry.

Right now if someone puts in Apple.com it shows up as Apple.com.

How would I make it so they could put in a url, which would append "http://" to it, and then a title, such as "Apple", so it shows up as "Apple" but as an active link?

I assume I would have to add to my database as well to store both the title and the url.

Right now I have

```
 <%= f.label :portfolio, "Personal Website" %>
 <%= f.text_field :portfolio, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do take necessary things from params and save to database

```
2.1.0 :009 > a = "Apple.com"
     => "Apple.com" 
    2.1.0 :011 > b = a.split(".")
     => ["Apple", "com"] 
    2.1.0 :012 > b[0]
     => "Apple" 
    2.1.0 :013 > c = "htpp://"+a
     => "htpp://Apple.com"
```

Or you can submit a hidden form 
https://jsfiddle.net/eLgqe2ya/2/